# UpdatePanel on Kindle Silk Browser

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, kindle

I'm having a heck of a time getting Kindle Silk to work with the UpdatePanel.

Depending on what page (apparently?) the user is on, one of two things happens:

1. The call succeeds and the response HTML is updated into the page but the Kindle's spinner icon keeps spinning.
2. The server is never called and an error message that gives no helpful information is displayed. I don't have it in front of me, but good chance it was something about an "unknown error".

Site works fine in IE, FireFox, Safari, Chrome, iPad, iPhone, etc.

Any particular difficulties with `UpdatePanel` on this platform? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kindle Silk/Amazon has a ton of caching in place.  They serve up content across their infrastructure(cloud browser) for parts of individual pages.  It is probably an issue with AJAX in general, however I can't point you to any documentation on that.

You will have to put up a proxy to watch the traffic to find out what the HTTP responses are for the request, my guess is you are getting HTTP 304s.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a way to disable Amazon's Cloud caching strategy, but it has to be set by the Kindle Fire user:
http://goo.gl/4M676

Comment: I haven't tried this to see if it would help yet, but it is of course unacceptable for an ecommerce website.